# Navigation ends up with hidden panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my first foray into using jquery mobile.. or any web development for that matter.

I've created a mockup at http://jsbin.com/riwuliwa/1/

The problem I'm facing is that if you open then left panel, navigate to Comments, and then to any other panel; everything works fine.
But if you come back to Main, and then try opening the left panel, its all botched up - the panel just won't open.

This errorneous behaviour is consistent for only the Main panel.

Comment: Your panels don't have unique ids. Try to not use the same id accross pages as they all exist within the DOM at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by ezanker, using unique ids solves the problem.

http://jsbin.com/riwuliwa/5